# Excel file added to ArcMap to check Statistics has data aligned left instead of right?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel, statistics

I have an excel file for average rainfall by month and I added that on ArcMap.

while I tried to check the statistics the tool is passive for last 3 months and I checked the data on arcmap, they are aligned left instead of right.

I can check the statistics for those which are right aligned but not for left aligned. Anybody can suggest me why they are left aligned.

I did multiple times for this with different sheets for same data but the result is same.

Comment: It seems like at least two potential answerers have struggled to understand what you are describing so I think you should **edit** your question to describe the precise steps needed to try and reproduce this.

Answer (score 2):

Left aligned in excel means that the values are stored as text instead of numbers. Try going back into excel and make sure the values are typed as numbers (e.g. 30.2 instead of 30.2in or 30.2"). If the numbers already look like numbers but are still left aligned, there should be an error message (normally a green triangle in the top left corner).

If that is the case, click in the cell and you get a warning diamond. Click on the warning diamond and select "Convert to Number" on the context menu.

I tried to generate a case of left aligned versus right aligned in ArcMap, but have not been able to do it. Is this an xls sheet or an xlsx sheet?

Comment: Thank you for your Answer Castillo. In excel, they are in right align but while they add in Arcmap, last few months will change in left align.

Comment: are there any blank rows?  if so the field is assessed as text/string.  alternately, format all columns explicitly as your desired number format

Comment: So, in arcmap, three of them are left aligned but the rest are right aligned? What does ArcMap think the column type is? Maybe you should save the sheet as a csv and try from there.